# Tagged pointer CRTP accessor class

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, crtp

I am about to implement tagged pointer which uses unused address bits to hold a payload. I am searching for effective way to access the payload. The declaration is as follows:

```
template<typename T, template<class> class PAYLOAD, DeleterType DELETER = DefaultDeleter<T>, size_t ALIGNMENT = alignof( T )>
class tagged_ptr;
```

It shares the basic principles with `unique_ptr` like the deleter etc. The issue I am facing is to use `PAYLOAD` template template parameter to define an accessor class to manipulate payload bits. The `PAYLOAD` shall be a class template containing just the accessor functions (getters/setters), no data. The idea is to use the `PAYLOAD` as **CRTP** base class of `tagged_ptr` to grant the access to it's private data - the pointer itself (`uintptr_t` - the address the tagged_ptr holds). So I tried to define it as:

```
template<typename T, template<class> class PAYLOAD, DeleterType DELETER = DefaultDeleter<T>, size_t ALIGNMENT = alignof( T )>
    class tagged_ptr : public PAYLOAD<tagged_ptr> { ... }
```

but it does not compile reporting:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class> class PAYLOAD'
[build]    15 |  class tagged_ptr : public PAYLOAD<tagged_ptr> {
[build]       |                                              ^
```

So my question is -

> how to implement a CRTP for derived class template?

In normal CRTP the pattern is like

```
template<typename DERIVED>
class Base { /* use static casts to DERIVED to access its data */ }

class Derived : public Base<Derived> { ... }
```

means the `Derived` is not a class template, but in my case, it is... so how to solve it? Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename T, template<class> class PAYLOAD>
class tagged_ptr : public PAYLOAD<tagged_ptr<T,PAYLOAD>> {};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76517f052f79cd5e).

Comment: Ah so, I need to explicitly mention all the template parameters explicitly...thanks a lot! now it can compile :) marking as solved...

Comment: @MartinKopecký: Put differently, the injected-class-name (which provides the template argument list for you) is available only after the opening `{`.